# Как получить нужный объект из GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Есть GridPane. В ней объекты типа - label. 
Какие есть способы получения этих label?

UPD
Нашёл такое дело:

```
Label l = (Label) GridPane.getChildren().get(16);
```

Но суть в том, что у меня 6 колонок, в первой колонке у меня будет имя чего-то там и я хочу получать нужную строку по этой колонке.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь обыкновенным итератором коллекции и переберите все Label.  метод - public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод класса GridPane - getChildren() возвращает ссылку на коллекцию панели.